# Emby Server vs. Seagate USB

Tags: usb

Installed Ubuntu 18 and latest Emby server.  Install went fine, but I'm having difficulty setting up the library.  I have all media on a Seagate USB drive.  When browsing for Movie library location, it can't see the mount point of the drive.  I verified the directory is there and Ubuntu can browse the drive.  I thought the name might be an issue since it has spaces, but changing the label to "Seagate" didn't help. It appears Ubuntu is using udisksctrl to do the mount since it starts in "/media".  (Been a while since I did much with Linux... and it was called "UNIX" and didn't have a GUI.)

Comment: You need to mount it differently.

Comment: I wonder if you could expand on that a bit more?

Comment: Ubuntu and other automatically mount external drives in `/media` and for some reason Emby don't like it. I just use Disks, "cog wheel" > Edit mount points, turn off the switch then select all the other properties and it gets mounted in `/mnt`and then it works for Emby.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did something similar, using Disks but changed it to manual settings.  That seemed to do the trick, as you said.  (I kept it in the /media area.)